# Retrieve VM information from VCloud

Tags: powershell, vbscript, vmware-vcloud-director

In a development shop, we have a large number of VMs with complete installations of our applications, with client, server and database VMs in a single vApp. The people who create the VMs do not keep a registry of information about the vApps, and so in order to be able to find out a suitable vApp for testing from our development machines, it is a matter of trial and error, or if we are lucky, a note on the bug ticket.

Ideally, I would like to be able to query the vCloud for things such as:

- A list of Gold Master/All Templates obtainable for the "Add vApp from Catalog" screen.
- A list of already running instances of the vApp VMs (so as to save us the hassle of creating yet another copy), and the username of the owner.
- The name and external IP addresses of each VM in the vApp.

I am able to use Powershell and VBScript, so if someone could recommend a suitable interface, and even better, some sample code, this would be ideal.

Comment: You're looking for [PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/). It will let you do all that (and more) with relatively simply PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: Hmm. Tried that - sadly our server has an invalid certificate, and despite the 'ignore' value, I cannot connect to it. Interestingly, I can only connect using Firefox. Internet Explorer fails to connect as well as Powershell.